# Using find command on Mac, handling spaces and ( in filenames

Tags: macos, bash, unix, scripting, find

I am transferring a lot of Mac data from a user to a Windows machine and am trying to remove all the illegal windows characters. I have used the following from another post, but this doesn't handle spaces or ( on the mac data.

```
find . -name "*[<>:\\|?*]*" -exec bash -c 'x="{}"; y=$(sed "s/[<>:\\|?*]\+/-  /g" <<< "$x") && mv "$x" "$y" ' \;
```

So I get  syntax error near unexpected token `(' for brackets

and  No such file or directory for those with spaces in.

Comment: You may have filenames with `"` in them. Try adding `set -x;` in the bash script.

Comment: I have filenames with spaces and filenames with brackets in them, these are what causing the issue, I don't want to remove the spaces or brackets just the characters windows doesn't like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested answer by @[meuh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5008284/meuh) does not work with OSX because it relies upon a non-POSIX regular expression. Probably it was written for [GNU sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions), which diverges in many respects from the standard.

[BREs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (used by [sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html#tag_04_126_13_02)) do not accept a `+` in this expression.  Instead, one uses the range followed by zero-or-more copies (`*`) of the range.

Here is a working script:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -name "*[<>:\\|?*]*" 2>/dev/null |
sed "p; s/[<>:\\|?*][<>:\\|?*]*/-  /g" |
while read x; read y
do
   if test "X$x" != "X$y"
   then
       mv -v "$x" "$y"
   fi
done
```

and output (starting with a file named `".baf fled/f<>foo2."`):

```
./baf fled/f<>oo2. -> ./baf fled/f-  oo2.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternative which should work with any sequence of chars:

```
find . -name "*[<>:\\|?*]*" |
sed "p; s/[<>:\\|?*]\+/-  /g" |
while read x; read y
do  mv "$x" "$y"
done
```